# A set contains elements in an AP , prove it has infinite composite numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Consider $S=\{a,a+d,a+2d...\}$ where $a$ and $d$ are positive integers. Show that there are infinitely many composite numbers in $S$.

---

I found this question in a book named "Challenge and thrill of pre college mathematics" ; and would be grateful for hint or the solution .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Proof by contradiction* works.

Suppose that, $S_k=a+kd>1$ is the last composite number, where $a,d\in\mathbb Z_{>0}$. Then consider:

$$S_{k^{'}}=S_k+ S_k d$$

A contradiction.

Comment: Nice!!! Approach indeed!!!

Comment: @Math_Buddy Thanks for checking the answer.

Comment: Thnx for helping with the solution, i understood it

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Case 1:}$ $a>1$ then consider the sequence $$T(k)=a+a^kd$$ for each $k>1$

$\textbf{Case 2:}$ $a=1$ and $d>1$ then define $$T(2n)=d.d^{2n}+1=d^{2n+1}+1=(d+1)(d^{2n}-...+1)=f(d)g(d)$$ where $f(d)=d+1$ note that $g(d)$ cannot be 1 because if so then $d^{2n+1}=d$ also $d+1>0$ and $d^{2n+1}+1>0$ so $g(d)>0$ as $g(d)$ is a positive integer $>1$ we are done as any way# $d+1>1$

$\textbf{Case 3:}$ If $a,d=1$ Then $S=\mathbb{N}$

Answer (score -1):

Wlog $a>1$ (else drop the first term). Then whenever $n$ is a multiple of $a$, so is $a+nd$.